# Laravel nova getting the ID value of the created model in the fillUsing callback of the field

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am developing a Web application using Laravel Nova. Laravel Nova is quite a new technology. Now, what I am doing now is overriding the Field callback to add own business logic rather than performing the database operation. See my scenario below.

This is my fields method of my resource

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make("Subject")->fillUsing(function(){
                //here, I like to get the id of the created model. How?
            }),
            Text::make('Title')->sortable()
        ];
    }
```

As you can see that I am overriding the logic of the Subject field. I like to fetch the Id of the model inside the callback. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you take a look at the `Field.php` class, you will see this is how the `fillCallback` is used:

```
protected function fillAttribute(NovaRequest $request, $requestAttribute, $model, $attribute)
{
    if (isset($this->fillCallback)) {
        return call_user_func(
            $this->fillCallback, $request, $model, $attribute, $requestAttribute
        );
    }

    $this->fillAttributeFromRequest(
        $request, $requestAttribute, $model, $attribute
    );
}
```

Therefore, inside your callback function, you can access the variables like this:

```
Text::make('Subject')->fillUsing(function($request, $model, $attribute, $requestAttribute) {
    dd($model->id);
});
```